# The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded even after changing to 2147483647

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I'm using a WCF client and call a method `GetEmployeeId`. In `GetEmployeeId` method, I have a return statement.

```
return employeeid;
```

When I add a breakpoint on `employeeid` - it has 4984 id's.

Once I click on continue, I am getting the following error:

> Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring to default configuration, or refreshing the service.
>
> Inner Exception:
>   The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

In the client and service, I am using:

```
<bindings>
   <basicHttpBinding >
      <binding name="MybasicHttpBinding" 
           maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
           maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647" />
      </binding>
   </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

and the endpoint address is :

```
<endpoint 
    address="http://localhost/EmployeeService/Service.svc" 
    binding="basicHttpBinding" 
    bindingConfiguration="MybasicHttpBinding"
    contract="Employee.Contract.IEmployee" >
```

Answer (score 0):

The number of IDs being less than the max size quota is easily possible.  If you have, for example, a very basic ID that looks like

5

then even though it's "1" record, it takes up 26 bytes of "size".